# What is different between using package.json and usign http-proxy-middleware module to create proxy?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, proxy

I wonder why the react application doesn't make request to back end service when client accesses to root page when using `proxy` option in `package.json` file.

Here is my code.
Front end service is react project.
Back end service is spring boot project.

###### spring boot controller

```java
package blog.in.action.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class CorsController {

    @GetMapping(value = {"", "/"})
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("index");
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/not-cors")
    public String notCors() {
        System.out.println("not-cors");
        return "notCors";
    }

    @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping(value = "/cors")
    public String cors() {
        System.out.println("cors");
        return "cors";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/not-proxy")
    public String notProxy() {
        System.out.println("not-proxy");
        return "notProxy";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/proxy")
    public String proxy() {
        System.out.println("proxy");
        return "proxy";
    }
}
```

###### react App.js

```js
import './App.css';
import {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    const responseHandler = ({data}) => {
        setMessage(data);
        return data;
    };

    const errorHandler = ({message}) => {
        setMessage(message);
        return message;
    };

    const onNonCorsHeaderHandler = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/not-cors')
            .then(responseHandler)
            .catch(errorHandler);
    };

    const onCorsHeaderHandler = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/cors').then(responseHandler);
    };

    const onNonProxyHandler = () => {
        axios.get('/not-proxy')
            .then(responseHandler)
            .catch(errorHandler);
    };

    const onProxyHandler = () => {
        axios.get('/proxy').then(responseHandler);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>
                {message}
            </p>
            <div>
                <button onClick={onNonCorsHeaderHandler}>non cors header</button>
                <button onClick={onCorsHeaderHandler}>cors header</button>
                <button onClick={onNonProxyHandler}>nonProxy</button>
                <button onClick={onProxyHandler}>proxy</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

### Using `proxy` option in `package.json` file

When I create a proxy in react application by using package.json file.

```json
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

###### React Application root path

[image]

### Using `http-proxy-middleware` module

When I create a proxy in react application by using `setupProxy.js` file for `http-proxy-middleware` module.

```js
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = app => {
    app.use('/',
        createProxyMiddleware(
            {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                changeOrigin: true,
            }
        )
    )
}
```

###### React Application root path

[image]